# What's causing the NullPointerException?

Tags: android

Im just coding the Android application which I thought of in order to learn the SDK a little more and ran into a problem when trying my program with the emulator. The application installs normally and then closes only to give me a logcat saying theres a NullPointerException in the main class. I cant manage to find it anywhere and research says that theres an object being used without it being initialized? I dont think this is possible as if it were the case, Eclipse would give me an error, but in this case it is a runtime exception. I do not have a lot of programming experience especially in Android and this bug is stopping me from seeing if the rest of my program works!

Heres the [Source](http://pastebin.com/hFiX71uc)

and heres the [Logcat](http://pastebin.com/QMBeaa3a)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are you sure every `View` you are using is inside your `activity_iowe_you.xml` and `activity_iowe_you.xml` exists?

Comment: can you debug your (little) program from first line and go step-by-step until exception occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs on line 80 in your onCreate method in IOweYou.java. You can see it on line 19 in the stacktrace you posted.

```
08-03 07:11:35.068: E/AndroidRuntime(681):      at com.andrei.iou.IOweYou.onCreate(IOweYou.java:80)
```

Is localEL properly defined?

EDIT:
make your activity extend ExpandableListActivity instead of activity. Then remove setContentView. And change

```
localEl.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

to

```
this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and your list will show. However clicking on the item will still make it crash but its a start!

EDIT2:
here is an example I found. 
http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com.es/2010/04/expandablelistactivity-in-android.html

Comment: I already suggested your edit in my answer. If you want to elaborate on it, you could edit that answer instead of changing your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your `ExpandableListActivity localEl` has been created but not launched. When you call `localEL.setListAdapter(mAdapter);` it internally calls its `setContentView`, as is shown in the log. Probably `getWindow()` returns null because the activity has not yet been initalized.

Without knowing much of what you want to do, perhaps your activity should instead inherit from ExpandableListActivity?